# Google Tag Manager custom javascript failed in IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am a beginner to use GTM, and I want to track how many users click on the two links.

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="XXX.XXX.XXX" title="ABC"><span>YYY</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="XXX.XXX.XXX">YYY</a></li>
</ul>
```

The only different between the two link is one has "title" and is surrounded by "span" tag.

I try to use custom javascript to return different value.

```
function(){
    var ele = {{element}}; //this should be the "a" tag
    var ref = ele.getAttribute("href");
    var tit = ele.getAttribute("title");
    var inner = ele.innerHTML.toString();

    if({{user_if_mpf}} == true && (tit !== null)){
        var str = ele.childNodes[0].innerHTML + " (From First line)";
        return str; 
    }
    else if({{user_if_mpf}} == true){
        return ele.innerHTML + " (From Second line)";
    }
}
```

This works fine in Chrome, but when I test it on IE8, when I click the first line, it returns 
    YYY (From Second line)

Can someone help me to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry about the format of the code....It's my first time using Stackoverflow

Comment: Correction: on IE8, when I click first line, it returns "<SPAN>YYY</SPAN> (From Second line)". There is a span tag...

Comment: What do you want it to return? Just the text without the tags?

Comment: Yes, I want to get the inner text and the "(From first/second line)"

Answer (score 0):

If you can add a class to your anchor tags, you can fire the tags using the Link Click event listener tag.

For example, add gtm_phone to anchor tag:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="XXX.XXX.XXX" title="ABC" class="gtm_phone"><span>YYY</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="XXX.XXX.XXX" class="gtm_phone">YYY</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then, create an event within GTM:

[image]

The `{{element - text}}` macro is just a Auto-Event Variable > Element Text:

[image]

Finally, add your rule:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately I cannot modify the code. I can only modify things in the GTM...